# Posting to strand from coroutine doesn't work

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Big enterprise project. I have single io_service instance: ios_.

I use coroutine (boost::asio::spawn)

Sometimes (not always), when I post a function to a boost::asio::strand from coroutine (!!!!) - this function doesn't called. There is nothing on this strand, and there's no stackoverflow error.

My question is: why the fucntion doesn't called? Is there some principial race, or problem in system resources?

```
        boost::asio::spawn(ios_, [...]                  (boost::asio::yield_context asio_yield)
        { 
            // BIG asynchronous code

             boost::asio::strand strand1(ios_);
             strand1.post([](){ 
                             // light code. 
                             // sometimes we don't get here
                               cout << "posted to a strand"
                               });

         });
```

1) If we exit coroutine before posting to a strand (for example, by posting to ios_) - it works well, we always get to a function

2) if we use another instance of boost::asio::io_service in boost::asio::spawn - it also orks well

3) we have enough threads in thread_pool (12), when we start boost::asio::io_service

4) used: 1.63 boost

The only lesson I have learned: leave coroutine as fast as possible. But we the program behave this way - I didn't get

Comment: Are you able to make a [mcve] that would exhibit the problem you see? Otherwise the most likely answer you are going to get is "the problem is in the code you are not showing us".

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't. Code inside the coroutine is very big and heavy.

Comment: So you have tried to make a reduced example that just has the things you mentioned in your question and the other code replaced by a bunch of sleeps? And it does not exhibit the problem? So... the problem is in the other code. :-)

Comment: What happens if you give the strand longer lifetime? I'm not convinced it matters (in fact, I don't think it does), just seems easy to check (if all else fails, make it a shared pointer and capture a copy in the posted lambda)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. strand1 lives long (it's class member). There's something else. I thought: coroutine is strand itself. May be there's conflict between strands, something like that..